# POST returns "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

The way the project works is there should be a random code that is given in creating a room (avoiding duplicates and the guessing a code that isn't taken) and the host should create their own name.

In the files, I've created the room and generated a random code that should be given when creating a room, but I receive an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed. I'm attempting to POST and not GET so I'm confused as to why that's happening; and the other parameters (code and host) do not show up. I assumed the code and host key would show up in the create method, but it doesn't. I would also like to add that I receive and Integrity Error regardless of changing the serializer to add id, code, and host to the serializer or if I leave the code the way it is in the screenshots.

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import random
import string

# Create your models here.

def code():
    """
    function randomly creates room access code
    """
    length = 7

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break

        return code
        
class Room(models.Model):
    """
    sets up room requirements and stores it as a model
    """
    code            = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=code,
                                        unique=True)
    host            = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    guest_can_pause = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    votes_to_skip   = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model   = Room
        fields  = ('id', 'code', 'host', 'guest_can_pause',
                    'votes_to_skip', 'created_at')

class CreateRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model   = Room
        fields  = ('guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Room
from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer, UpdateRoomSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, status


# Create your views here.

class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    collects all parameters from a serializer to show an existing room
    """
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer


class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    """
    creates a room using the POST method and accesses the serializer for the
    parameters
    """
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data['guest_can_pause']
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data['votes_to_skip']
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)

            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                            votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                room.save()
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            
        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Could you put the code as code not as screenshot?

Comment: use postman, then you won't get any error because if you pass the URL in the browser it is always(GET) said like that only

Answer (score 4):

The POST request in POSTMAN can get converted to GET during redirects and give you HTTP 405 error:
{
"detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."
}

. To avoid this you can go to the Setting (near Params, Auth.. ) in the request and click OFF to ON below items:

Follow original HTTP Method -> click ON
Redirect with the original HTTP method instead of the default behavior of redirecting with GET.

Follow Authorization header -> click ON
Retain authorization header when a redirect happens to a different hostname.

Comment: This fixed my problem but then I investigated why it was redirecting and it was for the lack of a slash at the end of the URL

Answer (score 1):

It's actually due to the first request your browser makes to your server when you open the current URL and it is a get request because of which server response as getting if not allowed.

If you still want to  have a get method try to use modelViewset they are amazing and very flexible go through this doc.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: how do I fix that?

Comment: if you want you can add a get method to the class-based view but I don't you need it just ignore it, as it will not hamper anyone else consuming your APIs.

Comment: @triedit if you still want to fix it write get method for the view or use any of the model view set which has all these method defaults written go through modeviewset and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this **`class CreateRoomView(APIView):`** try this **`class CreateRoomView(generics.ListCreateApiView):`** if you want get and post method to work with the view. And if you only want post method than **`class CreateRoomView(generics.CreateAPIView):`**

Comment: doesn't change the output and the second gives an assertion error. thank you for responding.

Comment: It is not an error because the browser makes a get request when you open the api url as Dev Kumar mentioned. You should use tools like postman or curl to test your api views

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response.